# Check the list of applications which have subscribed as windows clipboard listeners

Tags: c#, clipboard

I've subscribed my *winform* application to the windows clipboard listener list.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg != WmClipboardupdate) return;
    //Do somthin
}
```

Is there anyway to check the windows clipboard listener list to see *what other applications have subscribed there* and also *make sure that my application has subscribed there just once*?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not get the listener list in existing [`Clipboard API list`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx)

You do not need to make sure your application subscribed just once, since the `AddClipboardFormatListener` will return `false` if same handled registered before.

Comment: Using a different DLL maybe?